# Table-valued function

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Necesito crear Funciones definidas por el usuario con valores de tabla, ¿Se puedo crear desde EF? o ¿Solo lo creo por transac sql y después lo represento en el modelo? ¿Como trabajaría con EF en este caso?

Nota: Estoy trabajando con EF enfoque code firts.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnDetalleCaja(@desde datetime2, @hasta datetime2) RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN (SELECT .... WHERE ...)
```

La entidad DetalleCaja saldría de esa función.  Para EF debería ser para todos los efectos la misma cosa.

Para este caso creo mi table-value funtion por codigo transact sql y despues creo mi entidad en mi capa de entidades.

¿Cual es la forma de trabajar en este caso?

Comment: muestranos un ejemplo de lo que has intentado o de lo que deseas hacer. Entiendo que lo que quieres hacer es mapear un procedimiento como función en EF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teniendo la instancia de la db desde el contexto de EF podrias ejecutar comandos

[Raw SQL Queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx)

```
string query = "CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnDetalleCaja(@desde datetime2...";

using (var context = new xxContext()) 
{ 
   context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query);
}
```

**>>¿Ese código debe ejecutarse cada vez que ejecuto el sistema, me imagino que debe de trabajar asi como se hace el mapeo de las clases map, en el cual EF siempre revisa si esta creada la db y las tablas?**

si debe crearse cuando se define la estructura enconces vas a necesitas implementarlo en Migrations

[Code First Migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx)

Comment: Al crear Table-valued function para DetalleCaja, ¿En mi modelo de clases también lo implementaria y posteriormente en mi dominio de entidades?, Por la respuesta que me das iria en mi capa de persistencia justo en DetalleCajaRepsository esto asumiendo que tengo que implementarlo en mi modelo y en DominioEntidades. ¿Ese código debe ejecutarse cada vez que ejecuto el sistema, me imagino que debe de trabajar asi como se hace el mapeo de las clases map, en el cual EF siempre revisa si esta creada la db y las tablas?